# Buying PC for Autonomous Driving Software and Simulator

Tags: graphics-cards, processor

I am currently going to buy PCs for my university for the purpose of using Autonomous Programming Software and the simulator. The simulator we currently use is CARLA and we had an issue where the current PC is very laggy when running CARLA and ROS packages for the Autonomous Driving Software. The specs of the current PC are as below:

[image: Current PC specs]

I am planning to get new PC with specs as below:

Processor: Intel Core i7-12700K or i7-12700
RAM: 32GB DDR4
GPU: NVIDIA RTX 3080 (12GB) or NVIDIA RTX A2000 (12GB) (12 GB VRAM)
Storage: 1TB SSD PCIe NVMe

I mainly have questions about the GPU. As one of them is GeForce series and another is Quadro series. Both are hard to compare for this particular scenario. The system requirement of CARLA only states that it requires 6 GB VRAM but prefer 8 GB VRAM. If I am going to continue to develop the autonomous driving code with CARLA as simulator or maybe any other simulators like LGSVL in the future for maybe 5 years, which GPU is more suitable? I have tried to search online and ask other Pros but I didnt get any good answers as this scenario is too specific. Or maybe the processor is not suitable.

Comment: The only difference I know of between Quadro and Geforce are the drivers. If you currently use nouveau, there should be no difference

Comment: Quadro cards do have some extra hardware capabilities, the drivers have to be different because the functions of the GPU are different too. I'm not sure that CARLA or LGSVL actually needs the functionality of a Quadro though. Is it just for rendering to the screens or is there any kind of GPU compute (OpenCL / CUDA) being done?

Comment: Do you know if your software / own code use more basic math or more if/else stuff? If last, cpu would be much more important, if the first, definitely your gpu, if both well then you would need a more ‚normal‘ pc config like you mentioned to eye on. But i would definitely think about that - and if you don‘t know yet, buy a large enough case for now;)

Answer (score 0):

I think I would get 64gb of Ram, the 3080 should be good but get the 10gb version if possible.  It seems your build meets the recommended specs as per CARLA who refer users to the Unreal engine specs

Performance Notes(https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/hardware-and-software-specifications-for-unreal-engine/)

This list represents a typical system used at Epic, providing a reasonable guideline for developing games with Unreal Engine 5:

Windows 10 64-bit

64 GB RAM

256 GB SSD (OS Drive)

2 TB SSD (Data Drive)

NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER

Xoreax Incredibuild (Dev Tools Package)

Six-Core Xeon E5-2643 @ 3.4GHz

CARLA recommended specs
https://unrealcommunity.wiki/recommended-hardware-x1p9qyg0